# Problema do Segredo do Cofre - OBI 2017

Tags: python-3.x, lista, for

Estou resolvendo o seguinte problema da OBI: https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/p1/2017/f1/cofre/

Segredo do Cofre
O sistema de segredo para abrir esse cofre é bastante complexo. Ao invés de girar um botão várias vezes, como a gente vê normalmente nos filmes, o dono do cofre tem que deslizar um controle para a esquerda e para a direita, em cima de uma barra, várias vezes, parando em determinadas posições. A barra possui N posições e cada posição contém um número inteiro entre 0 e 9, inclusive. No exemplo da figura, a barra tem 14 posições e o controle está na posição 1.

O segredo vai depender de quantas vezes cada um dos dez inteiros entre 0 e 9 vai aparecer dentro do controle. Por exemplo, suponha que o dono deslize o controle da posição inicial 1 até a posição 9, depois para a posição 4, depois para a posição 11 e por fim até a posição 13. Veja que o inteiro 1, por exemplo, vai aparecer seis vezes dentro do controle; e o inteiro 9 vai aparecer quatro vezes.

Dada a sequência de inteiros na barra e a sequência de posições entre as quais o dono desliza o controle, começando da posição inicial 1, seu programa deve contar quantas vezes cada inteiro, entre 0 e 9, vai aparecer dentro do controle.

Entrada
A primeira linha da entrada contém dois inteiros N e M, representando o número de posições na barra do cofre e o número de posições na sequência que o dono vai seguir para deslizar o controle. A segunda linha contém N inteiros entre 0 e 9, definindo a barra do cofre. A terceira linha contém M inteiros representando a sequência de posições que o dono vai seguir. A primeira posição nessa sequência é sempre 1 e não há duas posições consecutivas iguais.
Saída
Seu programa deve imprimir uma linha contendo 10 inteiros, representando o número de vezes que cada inteiro, entre 0 e 9, vai aparecer no controle da barra.
Restrições
2 ≤ N ≤ 105 e 2 ≤ M ≤ 105
Informações sobre a pontuação
Em um conjunto de testes somando 40 pontos, N ≤ 1000 e M ≤ 1000

Este é meu código:
https://github.com/DaviColaresR2-D2/OBI-Problemas/blob/master/Cofre%2Cpy3

```
N, M = input().split(" ")
N, M = int(N), int(M)
cfo = input().split(" ")
for x in range(N): cfo[x] = int(cfo[x])
cfs = input().split(" ")
for x in range(M): cfs[x] = int(cfs[x])
cfi = []
cfp = []
for x in cfs:
    for y in range(x):
        cfi.append(cfo[y])
print(cfi)
for x in range(10):
    cfp.append(cfi.count(x))
print(cfp)
```

O meu problema é percorrer a lista, por exemplo se algo vai para a posição 5 da lista, e o próximo têm de ir pra 6, ele corre apenas uma posição, mas meu programa está correndo 7 posições (contando com o 0), a cada for ele recomeça.

Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Por favor, copie o enunciado e o seu código para a pergunta, pois se um dos links ficar indisponível sua pergunta deixará de fazer sentido.

Comment: Corrigido, você poderia me ajudar agora?